# Using == to compare cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, int64

I have 2 data frames: df1 and df2.

Both have a column with the same name and expecting 1 integer value
When I try to compare as such:

`df1['COLUMN'].iloc[0] == df2['COLUMN'].iloc[0]`, it gives false.

However, on checking the data, both values are same and both types are numpy.int64

If I modify the dataframes as so:

`df1.astype(int)
df2.astype(int)`

`df1['COLUMN'].iloc[0] == df2['COLUMN'].iloc[0]` returns True.

Can someone please help me understand why the == is returning false if the type is numpy.int64?

Comment: Can you add code responsible for creating said `pandas.DataFrame`s?

Comment: Can you post your dataframe along with their dtype

Comment: I am fetching the data from snowflake like so:  df = cursor.execute(sql).fetch_pandas_all()